# How to scrub data in Excel, specifically removing extreme outliers that are outside of a given range?

Tags: excel, data-scrubbing

I have thousands of cells of data that are output from a model, with my results formatted as follows: cell ID is column header, each row is a timestep, and each cell's results over hundreds of timesteps is printed out in a spreadsheet. I want to analyze the data within certain percentiles. I've identified what the values are for the percentile thresholds of interest, but I'm not finding clear directions on how to ...

a) remove all values that are outside of the range I'm interested in, for the sheet I'm working in

or

b) pull the values within the range of interest out of the sheet and into a separate one for further analysis

The values are numbers with two decimal places.

I need to scrub the data, then analyze it, in a separate step. For example, even after removing the extreme max and min in a timeseries, I still want to see the entire timeseries but with the outliers removed or changed to a null value. **How can I select or simply remove all the outliers from this data matrix, leaving the rest of the data in tact?**

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do it is using the PivotTable feature.

With the PivotTable you will be able to create filter parameters using ranges (the main data and the outliers as well).

Please, take a look on this if you don't know how to use a PivotTable:
[Create a PivotTable to analyze worksheet data](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)

Comment: Maybe I need to clarify the question: I need to scrub the data, then analyze it, in a separate step. For example, even after removing the extreme max and min in a timeseries, I still want to see the entire timeseries but with the outliers removed or changed to a null value. Could a pivot table still be used for that purpose?

Comment: IMHO its the best way to do it. You will keep you source of information intact and complete. Cause you will need to define "what" and "where" are yours outliers first and then start your analysis.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go tomorrow and will accept your answer or let you know why if I don't

Comment: I haven't been able to figure out how pivot tables would accomplish this. They seem to only summarize data, but I need my original data table in tact just with outliers removed from the many columns and corresponding timeseries.

Comment: @cr0 you can filter your data in the pivotable... https://support.content.office.net/en-us/media/48c78fc8-1616-4486-9b71-21eda8e452e6.png

Answer (score 1):

Although "Robust" the easiest way to do this would to to filter your data. After that, filter out all of your good values. Once you only have the "bad" cells visible, then go to special and highlight only visible cells. From there, delete.

To do this efficiently / with keyboard shortcuts, it would be like so:

- 1) Select the data headers and type `alt + h + s + f`
- 2) Click the "value" header, and click proper numbers until you have all the data you do not want filtered out.
- 3) Highlight all of the remaining cells (These should be the data points you want deleted, and the row numbers in excel should be blue now)
- 4) Type `alt + h + f + d + s + y` to go to special and select visible cells only
- 5) Type `alt + h + d + r` to remove the rows (this will take a bit of time, be patient)

I hope it works!

***EDIT: Instead of manually sorting out the data, you can also rank based off of size, and directly cut the data like that. After thinking more about the answer, this method would be easier (I think) and much faster.

Comment: @cr0 any luck with this implementation?